# Modify list item on click with Javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, list

I'm trying to create a basic to-do list in Javascript. I have basically zero experience with this language, so I'm trying to keep it as basic as possible. I want to have the appearance of the list item change when the user clicks on it (have a line strike through the text, for example). I've been using other sources for some of the JavaScript, but for some reason it isn't working with my code.

Here are the problem spots.

```
<script>
var list = document.querySelector('ul');
list.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
   if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
   ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
  }
}, false); 
</script>

<html>
<ul id = "toDoList">
    <li id = "checked">Do laundry</li>
    <li>Wash car</li>
</ul>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.checked {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

If someone could help me solve this problem, that would be awesome! (also, steer clear from JQuery, I don't know anything about it.)

Comment: what does actually **not** work?

Comment: By the way, you should have a body tag. Also, right clicking and selecting "inspect element" is helpful for finding errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run the javascript code after the element has been loaded, otherwise you won't find it and the code won't work.

```css
.checked {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<html>
<ul id = "toDoList">
    <li id = "checked">Do laundry</li>
    <li>Wash car</li>
</ul>
<script>
var list = document.querySelector('ul');
list.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
   if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
   ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
  }
}, false); 
</script>
</html>
```

Another possibility is to still have the code on top but make it so it runs after the page is loaded with `window.onload` - the function you assign will run after the page is loaded.

```css
.checked {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<html>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
  var list = document.querySelector('ul');
  list.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
     if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
     ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
    }
  }, false); 
}
</script>
<ul id = "toDoList">
    <li id = "checked">Do laundry</li>
    <li>Wash car</li>
</ul>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code to solve your issue. 
HOWEVER I think you should learn JavaScript if you want to code in JavaScript. JS language has similar syntax to other C-like languages (C, C++, Java, etc...) but under the hood it's very different.

The code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <style>
            .checked {
                text-decoration: line-through;
            }
        </style>
        <ul>
            <li class="item">task 1</li>
            <li class="item">task 2</li>
        </ul>
        <script>
        (function()
        {
            var items = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("item"));
            items.forEach(function(item)
            {
                item.onclick = function()
                {
                    item.className += " checked";
                }
            });
        })();
        </script>
    </body>
<html>
```